# Summation overloading

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading

I want the summation of 3 different objects like:

```
`2 3 4
 2 3 4
 2 3 4  
 6 9 12`the summation must be like this
```

And tried to do this

```
`

class mymath:
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.z=z        
    def __add__(self,other):
        return self.x+other.x, self.y+other.y, self.z+other.z
x=mymath(2,7,6)
y=mymath(4,3,8)
z=mymath(2,4,6)
print(x+y+z)
```

Comment: dunder `__add__` must return the result, not perform side effects.

Comment: Look to it again

Comment: typo `self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y+self.z+other.z` => `self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y,self.z+other.z` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a tuple, which doesn't have the `__add__()` method overloaded. You should return a `mymath` object instead:

```
class mymath:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z        

    def __add__(self, other):
        return mymath(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z)

    def __str__(self):
        return "({}, {}, {})".format(self.x, self.y, self.z)

x = mymath(2, 7, 6)
y = mymath(4, 3, 8)
z = mymath(2, 4, 6)
print(x + y + z) # Result: (8, 14, 20)
```

**Edit: clarification of the solution added after comment**

Each `+` sign translates to an `__add__()` call. In your example, the operation `x + y + z` is actually performing two calls to `__add__()`: `x.__add__(y).__add__(z)`.

Adding parentheses to the expression may help: `x + y + z` actually translates to `(x.__add__(y)).__add__(z)`.

The problem happens in the second call to `__add__()`, since your method is returning `self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z` which is the tuple `(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z)` (you can omit the parentheses in your code, and it's more pythonic, but it's equivalent and it's actually a tuple).

A tuple is a fixed-length list of elements and it's a basic class of python language. You can read more about it [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/tuple/).

The result of `x.__add__(y)` is the summation you would expect from `x + y`, but of type `tuple`. In the example, `(6, 10, 14) == (2 + 4, 7 + 3, 6 + 8)`

You can check this running your code but printing just `x + y`

```
print(x + y) # Prints (6, 10, 14)
```

And also:

```
print(type(x + y)) # Prints <class 'tuple'>
```

The second addition, though, fails, because the result of the first one is a tuple and not a `mymath` object. So `(x + y) + z` actually is calling the `__add__()` method of the tuple, which exists but has other meaning than the one you want. Therefore, you are obtaining the error `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "mymath") to tuple`

Note that adding two tuples is just appending them and not adding the coordinates element-wise: `(1, 2, 3) + (4, 5, 6) ==> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`

The solution to this problem is to return a `mymath` object as the result of the `__add__()` operation, allowing to concatenate more than one addition operation.

I added the [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method to your class because otherwise the print is just showing a default representation of the class like `<__main__.mymath object at 0x7f8654657390>`.

Comment: Can u explain more about tuple in this case?

Comment: I added a clarification to the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi. Is the answer ok? If so, could you accept it as the valid answer for the question? Thanks.